# Trying to write output by using Scrapy while crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl and get all the links from pages using scrapy.

When I run it like this in the terminal  `scrapy crawl crawl1 -o items.csv -t csv` . I do see that it does crawl and gets some links like follows but it doesn't write anything in the output file mentioned.

```
2016-12-05 16:17:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.abof.com/men/new-in/footwear> (referer: http://www.abof.com/)
2016-12-05 16:17:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.abof.com/> (referer: http://www.abof.com/)
2016-12-05 16:17:33 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.abof.com/skult> (referer: http://www.abof.com/)
```

I tried this out [Scrapy does not write data to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751323/scrapy-does-not-write-data-to-a-file) as well.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from crawl.items import CrawlItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst


class CrawlLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawl1"
    allowed_domains = ["www.abof.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.abof.com/"]
    #follow= True
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_items", ),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]')
        items = []
        l = CrawlLoader(CrawlItem(), hxs)
        for titles in titles:
            item = CrawlItem()
            # l.add_value("url",response.url)
            # l.add_xpath("title",titles.xpath("a/text()").extract())
            # l.add_xpath("link",titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()))

            item["title"] = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            item["url"] = titles.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
        # return l.load_item()
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

class CrawlItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:                                                                                                                                                            
    # name = scrapy.Field()                                                                                                                                                                                 
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried printing the items as you get them? (inside that `for` loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked this way by changing the parse_items function. Trying to parse images and other data inside of javascript now.

```
class CrawlLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawl1"
    allowed_domains = ["www.abof.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.abof.com/"]
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_items",follow= True ),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        href = CrawlItem()
        href['url'] = response.url
        href["title"] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
        return href
```